# How to address replacement error using merge raster?

Tags: r, r-raster

I am having some difficulty getting a number of DEM rasters to merge in R. I am using the below code:

```
library(raster)

setwd("D:/Europe_study_data/Raw data/DEM/Europe/DEM_100m/")

rasters = list.files(path = "./",
                     pattern = ".tif$",
                     full.names = T,
                     recursive = F)

allrasters <- lapply(rasters, raster::raster)
allrasters$na.rm <- TRUE
allrasters$tolerance = 0.5

DEM_mosaic = do.call(raster::merge, allrasters)

> DEM_mosaic = do.call(raster::merge, allrasters)
Error in vv[z1:z2, rc[j, 3]:rc[j, 4]] <- matrix(getValues(x[[rc[j, 5]]],  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, any help would be appreciated!

The rasters in question are just DEM data from Copernicus, here is a sample of them:

```
[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10000, 562, 5620000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 943750, 999950, 2e+06, 3e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : eu_dem_v11_E00N20.tif 
names      : eu_dem_v11_E00N20 
values     : 0, 892.1451  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10000, 10000, 1e+08  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 1e+06, 2e+06, 0, 1e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : eu_dem_v11_E10N00.tif 
names      : eu_dem_v11_E10N00 
values     : -0.3643485, 1933.337  (min, max)


[[3]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10000, 10000, 1e+08  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 1e+06, 2e+06, 1e+06, 2e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : eu_dem_v11_E10N10.tif 
names      : eu_dem_v11_E10N10 
values     : -0.1210834, 3669.544  (min, max)


[[4]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10000, 10000, 1e+08  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 1e+06, 2e+06, 2e+06, 3e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : eu_dem_v11_E10N20.tif 
names      : eu_dem_v11_E10N20 
values     : -0.9642857, 2277.056  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, and the better place to report these is [here](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues); but either way, it may be very difficult to find out what is going on without access to the data. You could try `terra::merge` instead ("terra" is the replacement of the "raster" package)

```
library(terra)
ff <- list.files(pattern = ".tif$")
rlist <- lapply(ff, terra::rast)

# make a SpatRasterCollection and merge
rsrc <- sprc(rlist)

m <- merge(rsrc)
```